# How can I get a string representation of an IPv4-mapped IPv6 that does not use a dotted quad?

Tags: go, formatting, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

Consider, for example, this [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Representation): `::ffff:7f7f:7f7f`. When submitting `http://[::ffff:7f7f:7f7f]` in the address bar of all browsers I've tested, the format is retained:

[image: omnibox]

However, the [`netip` package](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip) (more specifically, the [`String` method](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Addr.String) of [`netip.Addr`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Addr)) formats the address in question by writing its least-significant 32 bits in the IPv4 dot-decimal notation, like so: `::ffff:127.127.127.127`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/netip"
)

func main() {
    ip, err := netip.ParseAddr("::ffff:7f7f:7f7f")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(ip) // ::ffff:127.127.127.127
}
```

([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8cOQsCBgY7_p))

I need to replicate the way browsers' address bar format IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses.
Is there any way to get `netip` to format `::ffff:7f7f:7f7f`, not as `::ffff:127.127.127.127`, but as `::ffff:7f7f:7f7f`?

Comment: First, remember that IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses are not allowed to be used on a network, as explained in the _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_, Notice that they cannot be used as source or destination addresses, cannot be forwarded or globally routable, and they are reserved by IP itself They are not actual IPv6 addresses, only a representation of IPv4 addresses in the IPv6 format in order to have a common address store, e.g. database. They _should not_ work in your browser.

Comment: @RonMaupin I had missed that point. That is actually very good news for me, as it makes my life simpler! If you have time to convert your comment to an answer, I'll make sure to accept it.

Comment: OK, I did that.

Comment: FYI, I created a free [IP calculator](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX) that handles both IPv4 and IPv6, including all the valid IPv6 formats (expanded, compressed, expanded-mixed, and compressed-mixed), returning IPv6 addresses in RFC 5952 Canonical format.

Comment: @RonMaupin Nice. I ambition to write a fast parser for fully compressed IPv6 addresses specifically (it would reject uncompressed ones). Your calculator may come in handy as a reference.

Comment: The IP.pas file has the two IP objects, and the proper regular expressions for recognizing IP addresses.

Comment: Close-voter: how is this not reproducible?

Comment: I don't understand why you "need to replicate the way browsers' address bar format IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses".  Not to mention you don't specify which browsers you are talking about. This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @KurtisRader It's not an XY problem. This is for [a CORS middleware library](https://github.com/jub0bs/fcors). According to the Fetch standard, origin matching requires a byte-by-byte comparison. In my example, `::ffff:7f7f:7f7f != ::ffff:127.127.127.127`. Therefore, the CORS check would fail even if `http://[::ffff:7f7f:7f7f]` were allowed in the CORS configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remember that IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses are not allowed to be used on a network, as explained in the *[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)*, Notice that they cannot be used as source or destination addresses, cannot be forwarded or globally routable, and they are reserved by IP itself They are not actual IPv6 addresses, only a representation of IPv4 addresses in the IPv6 format in order to have a common address store, e.g. database. They *should not* work in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ipaddress-go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/), which can produce a variety of strings. Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the library.

```golang
addr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString("::ffff:7f7f:7f7f").GetAddress()
addrStr := addr.String()
fmt.Println(addrStr)
mixedAddrStr, _ := addr.ToIPv6().ToMixedString()
fmt.Println(mixedAddrStr)
```

Output:

```
::ffff:7f7f:7f7f
::ffff:127.127.127.127
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`net.IP`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IP.String) rather than `netip.Addr`, as per the docs:

[`Addr.String()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IP.String):

> Note that unlike package net's IP.String method, IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses format with a "::ffff:" prefix before the dotted quad.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but that's not the output I want. See https://go.dev/play/p/fDq6XLizjoo